# Ищу программу для редактирования элементов форм под курсором

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, поиск-программ

Когда то встречалась мне программка похожая на Resource Hacker , она позволяла навести курсор на контрол рабочей формы и можно было его отредактировать. Но не помню как она называется.

Comment: Поставьте метку [tag:поиск-программ] и прочитайте её описание. При чём тут цэ++?

Comment: @dIm0n При чём тут цэ++  - вроде она была с исходными кодами на плюсах, кажется что то даже изменял для себя. давно это было

Comment: Укажите это в вопросе, как и остальное, что требуется в описании метки

Comment: Учитесь пользоваться [поиском](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B+%D1%81+%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: Уточните, вам нужно в процессе разработки редактировать контролы в своей программе? Тогда просто используйте дизайнер WinForms, встроенный в Студию. Или вы хотите в чужой запущенной программе менять значения?

Comment: в чужой форме, наводишь курсор, получаешь handle и изменяешь его свойства